# Which is more common for everyday use?

Tags: phrase-usage, predicate, attributives

> 1. An old man is sitting on the bench.

Or

> 1. There is an old man sitting on the bench.

Comment: They are both fine, and might be used in slightly different contexts. [See this discussion](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/there-is-there-s-and-there-are).

Comment: The first is simply descriptive.  The second hints that "the old man" will be the subject of further discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure if you wrote about an old man on a bench every day, at some point you would know him well enough, to simply call him "The old man". :)

Jokes aside.

> An old man is sitting on the bench

and

> There is an old man sitting on the bench

are perfectly equivalent. Use them interchangeably, picking the one whose rhythm you prefer in the context of the surrounding sentences.